# Twitter bootstrap elements alignment

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I have `4 blocks on a row` that are displayed all on a single line on desktop, but when i resize the window (decrease the width), all the blocks will show on a diferent line. So i will get `one column with 4 lines` (4 elements) even though on one line can fit two elements.

`I expect 2 lines with 2 elements` insted of 4 lines with 1 element, to be more compact. How this can be done?

Here is the code:

```
<div class="content row">
    <section class="col col-lg-3">  
        <label>block 1</label>
    </section>
    <section class="col col-lg-3">  
        <label>block 2</label>
    </section>
    <section class="col col-lg-3">  
        <label>block 3</label>
    </section>
    <section class="col col-lg-3">  
        <label>block 4</label>
    </section>
</div>
```

Actual display:

```
------   ------   ------   ------ 
|    |   |    |   |    |   |    |
|    |   |    |   |    |   |    |
------   ------   ------   ------
```

Display after resizing:

```
---------------------------------
|                               |
|                               |
---------------------------------
---------------------------------
|                               |
|                               |
---------------------------------
---------------------------------
|                               |
|                               |
---------------------------------
---------------------------------
|                               |
|                               |
---------------------------------
```

Needed display after resizing:

```
---------------   ---------------
|             |   |             |
|             |   |             |
---------------   ---------------
---------------   ---------------
|             |   |             |
|             |   |             |
---------------   ---------------
```

Mention: bootstrap v3.0.0

Comment: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid    use col-md too   not just ld(large device)

Comment: There is class: class="row-fluid" in fluid grid system may b that's wat ur looking for..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked the [Grid-Options](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-options)?
There are classes like "col-xs-6" or "col-xs-3" etc. I belive with this you can change the behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<div class="content row">
    <section class="col col-lg-3 col-sm-6">  
        <label>block 1</label>
    </section>
    <section class="col col-lg-3 col-sm-6">  
        <label>block 2</label>
    </section>
    <section class="col col-lg-3 col-sm-6">  
        <label>block 3</label>
    </section>
    <section class="col col-lg-3 col-sm-6">  
        <label>block 4</label>
    </section>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes but 12 = 100% width. So if it reach 12, it should break the other 12 to a new line, or not?